# Use single spring boot application as a Spring boot admin and client both

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

We have one application which is running on the Spring boot, We don't like to add a new application in the environment to manage this application, to do so we like to add spring boot admin feature to the same application. I tried that and able to see the spring admin screen but the client is not getting loaded.

I don't know this is good idea or not.
Please provide your suggestion.

I can see it is working both spring boot admin sever and client both application in one.

But I dont know this is good idea or not. Please provide your inputs

Comment: Please add more specif details. Code you are stuck in or not working.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I tried to edit my post and update that I can run a both Admin and Client in my local within one spring boot application. But looks were not able to convey as needed. I can see my answer related to "It is good practice to use both in one application" from @f.trajkovski.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Spring Boot Admin is invented for monitoring multiple services. In my opinion you should separate them so everyone will has it's job to follow the single responsibility principle. With separation when your application will fail the Spring Boot Admin will catch logs and maybe some additional data, if they are together you won't know what might happen.